# git push success but not all files are being pushed

Tags: git

I have done a git push to my remote repository and it is success and when I try to clone the remote repository to another computer it didn't clone the whole file.

The flow file is like this: from my local computer -> to remote server -> to other computer.
using Git.

In my project file I have

> amon - this is a folder and there is another 2 folders in this folder. This folder is not copy
>
> Testrepo.txt
>
> secondtestfile

here is how my process look like.
[image]

please help.Thank you

Edited for the amon/folder structure:

[image]

Comment: try to see the logs with `git log` to figure out.

Comment: Only files are tracked by Git, not folders. So if you have no files inside a folder (or subfolder), you cannot keep track of it.

Comment: can you show your file/folder structure 
amon/folder_1/ 

amon/folder_2/ 

is this it? or there files inside your files ?

Comment: thks @roko. I have showed the file folders in the edited questions. there is also inside file. Its actually a django project and i wanted to git clone it into my remote server using git and after that share it to other user. I don't know if this the best way or its the best way using github?

Comment: To be more precise, git doesn't track files, it tracks "content". The filesystem layout of this content (i.e. what *path* a given blob of text is located at) is considered metadata. An empty folder has no content so git can't / won't track it.

Comment: thks @millimoose. I'm sorry i don't really get it..i am new in this git and we want to use git instead of svn. as far i can see there is content in each of the folder. well how do people in the github upload all their project and i can just clone it and its working???can i not use my own remote server as github? thanks

Comment: @Rhinodj for when you clone files from github and you get all the files and folders it's because there are contents inside those folders and they are not empty. Yes you can have your own remote server as bare/shared repository (github is just a web application which provides such facility, having your own repository is not termed as having github though)

Comment: @Rhinodj You should check whether the files *inside* `amon` are actually in Git - if none of them are, neither is the folder. Try to `git add` them explicitly, instead of using `git add .`. If they're being ignored or some such, git will complain. It's also a good idea to start with using a checkin tool like [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) to have a convenient way of seeing what's going on. (That will show you changes to tracked files as well as untracked files.)

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could provide a test case for us to poke at. E.g. delete most of the files from your repo except one-two without any sensitive information outside and inside `amon`, check whether the problem manifests when you try to push-pull to some testing remote repo, then ZIP this up and post the link?

Comment: thks @millimoose I will try to do what you wrote in her and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the red mark denotes, but it seems that your folder `amon` either is empty (no contents/files, just empty folders) or it is added to `.gitignore`. If you want it to be tracked then make sure it is not added to `.gitignore` file first. If it is not then, add some dummy file for now say `readme.txt` perhaps for now. Until your actual files are added to the folder. Make sure you add the file to git i.e. `git add amon/readme.txt` then commit your file, it should work.

Based on your comment [here's something](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/creating-a-shared-repository-users-sharing-the-repository/) for you to get started with using your own local computer or server as a shared repository which allows you and your colleagues to push/pull/fetch/merge your changes.

Comment: the red marks is because that folder is subversion. as u can see amon have 2 folders - metadata and this metadata have one more folder and 3 files and the other folder is amonsolution and in this amonsolution have 5 folders and each folders have files and other than folder it also have 4 files.i have done the one you have suggested and i can git add and its working but i cannot push it into the remote server.

Comment: thks @roko i will do based on the one you send..will check and hope it will be ok..get back to you.

Comment: hi @roko i have deleted all my setting and i start from scratch and i follow exactly what is stated in the guidelines. its working perfectly fine. my question is how can i copy in my django project (an existing files and folder) into "Amy's project1" and after that git push into origin(gitadmin) so that Zach may also get the same project? thanks

Comment: Hej @roko...a million thanks....i got it...i just follow exactly as the guide and i copy my project folder into zach and commit and push thru zach and then i git pull thru amy and 'walla' the file is updated. thanks a million..you made my weekend brighter...